# Number of functions (possibly involving empty set)

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I am asked how many functions there are from a set with $5$ objects to a set with $0$ objects and from $0$ objects to $5$ objects. I am having a bit of trouble and want to check my work.

From $5$ to $0$, I thought there is no such function since we cant map to the empty set. (and we defined naturals using set definitions)

From $0$ to $5$, I thought only one such, as the empty set is unique. But I'm not sure. Any comment?

Comment: Do you mean a function from a set of 5 objects to a set of zero objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of functions from $A$ to $B$ when $A$ and $B$ are finite is

$$\left\vert A^B\right\vert=\vert A\vert ^{\vert B\vert}.$$

So if $\vert A\vert=5$ and $\vert B\vert =0$:

$$\vert A\vert ^{\vert B\vert}=1$$

and

$$\vert B\vert ^{\vert A\vert}=0,$$

so your intuition is correct.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me see what I was thinking